# Ubuntu 16.04 - re-enabling disabled audio device which does not appear on PulseAudio

Tags: 16.04, drivers, sound, pulseaudio

This is going to be a fun one. I've disabled my laptop's internal speakers on some software level. I have not interfered with the hardware in any way and I am highly confident that they are still working. The problem is, I can no longer remember how I disabled them and therefore have not been able to figure out how to re-enable them. I've tried looking at PulseAudio's config files in order to jog my memory (the disabled device doesn't appear in the GUI, it's been disabled on some deeper level) but there doesn't seem to be anything that would appear to be my handiwork or any obviously non-default settings. What can I do?

Comment: Do you have sound in the guest account?

Comment: No. The audio setup seems to be identical to that of my main account.